# Variance Inflation Factor - can I make this assumption?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, correlation, descriptive-statistics, variance-inflation-factor

Let's assume I have a dataset with two numeric columns and I am assessing VIF for each variable:
`[x1, x2]`

Now let's assume that the calculation shows that variable `x1` has a VIF of `23.239`.

Can I assume, that if I calculate VIF using more covariates, that VIF for `x1` will never be lower? (the particular rows for x1 and x2 are exactly the same, I am just adding covariates in this example)

For example, `[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]` - will VIF for x1 always be greater than or equal to `23.239`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... will VIF for x1 always be greater than or equal to 23.239?

Yes. The [variance inflation factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor) is given by one over one less the $R^2$ from the given covariate regressed on all other covariates. The $R^2$ can only increase or stay the same as you add more covariates. Thus, $1/(1 - R^2)$ can only increase or stay the same.